# On which interface do I see the VLAN Tag packet

Tags: vlan

I am accessing two virtual machines running on CentOS. I have added one vlan on each machine:

On Machine 1- `10.11.20.22`

```
vconfig add eth1 2
ifconfig eth1.2 192.168.0.81 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255 up
```

and on Machine 2- `10.11.20.20`

```
vconfig add eth0 2
ifconfig eth0.2 192.168.0.84 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255 up
```

---

`route -n` on Machine 2 shows:

```
Destination       Gateway          GenMask         Iface
192.168.0.0       0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   eth0.2
10.11.20.0        0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   eth0
192.168.56.0      0.0.0.0          255.255.255.0   eth1
```

Now, when I use `ping -I eth0.2 192.168.0.81` from Machine 2 and run `tshark` on Machine 1 using `tshark -i eth0 -V >somefile`, it does not show the vlan tag, but with a little change,

if I use `ping -I eth0 192.168.0.81` from Machine 2 and run `tshark` on Machine 1 using `tshark -i eth0 -V >somefile`.

It shows the vlan tag.

What could be a possible explanation? How vlan tag info is transmitted and received in this case?

*I am trying to learn vlan and i am quite new to this field.*

Comment: I do not know `tshark`, but I do know that when using `tcpdump` (similar tool), you have to explicitly specify that you want to observe VLAN traffic. Maybe it's the same for `tshark`?

Answer (score 1):

The [Wireshark documentation on VLAN](http://wiki.wireshark.org/VLAN) is quite clear on this.

> To check for both VLAN-encapsulated and non-VLAN-encapsulated packets with that IPv4 address, try
>
> `host x.x.x.x or (vlan and host x.x.x.x)`

The [manpage](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) gives me `-f <capture filter>`

So I think this should work:

```
tshark -f vlan -i eth0 -V >somefile
```